# Intent Filter for XML files

Tags: android, intentfilter

I want to be able to open XML files in my app, when the user tries to open an xml file. There are many similar questions but I've tried a lot of them and nothing seems to help.

When I use these intent filters for PDF files it works perfectly (for PDF), but when I replace both mentions of 'pdf' with 'xml' it doesn't work for XML files even if the files are in the same folder.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file" 
          android:host="*"
          android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Try adding `text/xml` along with `application/xml` for the MIME type filter.  Note that neither will necessarily be the MIME type used by an app, as [the MIME type of XML files sometimes depends on the content of the XML itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_and_MIME). The second filter will become less relevant over time, as we stop using `file` schemes.

Comment: Adding `text/xml` did the trick, I would accept it as answer if I could ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `<intent-filter>` elements.

The first relies on a MIME type. `application/xml` is a possible MIME type for an XML file, but so is `text/xml`. And, for certain XML files, another MIME type might be used, based on the content of the XML (e.g., `application/atom+xml` for content written using the Atom schema). File managers and other "generic" content managers will tend to use whatever MIME type that `MimeTypeMap` reports for the file extension. Other apps, such as email clients and Web browsers, will use the MIME type reported by the server.

The second relies on a scheme (`file`) and a file extension (`.xml`). The `file` scheme is slowly fading away, and so this particular `<intent-filter>` will not be used much in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `application/xhtml+xml` solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks! I already used application/xml and text/xml but nothing. application/xhtml+xml did the trick (also application/*, but I don't want to open a file that my app doesn't support)...